# How to backport .NET 4's XmlConvert.IsWhitespaceChar to .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, xmlconvert

I need to backport some code that uses this method to .NET 3.5, and from Reflector I can't seem to discern what would be the correct way to provide my own C# implementation for it.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That method uses an embedded resource named XmlCharType.bin, you can see it with Reflector.  It is used by System.Xml.XmlCharType.get_Instance() to initialize the charProperties pointer.  That same resource is present in 3.5 as well, you could use it the same way.

Or take the lesser 3.5 approach:

```
WhitespaceChars = new char[] { ' ', '\t', '\n', '\r' };
```